# How to manually change/limit the amount of order items in the shopping cart?

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, cart-rule

How can I manually change/limit the amount of order items in the shopping cart?

For instance, the max items for France is 120, Switzerland is 12, while the rest of available countries is 60.

This is the input field for getting the total order from the cart's session.

```
<input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>"/>
```

Below is what I am currently doing but it does not effect the number of `$this->getQty()`

```
<?php if($shippingCountry === 'FR' || $shippingCountry === 'MC' || $shippingCountry === null):?>120<?php elseif($shippingCountry === 'CH'):?>12<?php else:?>60<?php endif;?>
```

I still get 120 for Switzerland for instance with `$this->getQty()` but it should be 12.

is it possible to change that?

Comment: Tealau,if you getting this message "The maximum quantity allowed for purchase.."  then it ok.it magento bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by hooking onto the event: sales_quote_save_before and check the total quantity of items in the quote. Something like:

```
public function myObserverMethod($Observer)
{

   $quote = $observer->getDataObject();
   foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){    
       $totalQty += $item->getQty();       
    }    
     if($totalQty > 60 ) //Whatever your conditions are
     {
         Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('Quantity limit exceeded');
         $quote->setHasError('true');
     }

    return $this;    

}
```

EDIT : Follow [this](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105) to create an observer for event: sales_quote_save_before

Comment: thanks but where can I locate `sales_quote_save_before`?

Comment: Edited my answer with a link.